# How to implement CORS in Reactor Netty?

Tags: java, project-reactor, reactor-netty

As you know, the CORS standards include initially sending an OPTIONS request to check validity, and I decided to release the processing of OPTIONS requests in the handler, but a problem arose to return a boolean value, and only process OPTIONS requests, and skip the rest in runOn, perhaps you know others ways to handle CORS helper requests?

```
public void run() {
    HttpServer.create()
            .host(this.config.getHost())
            .port(this.config.getPort())
            .runOn(eventLoopGroup.newEventLoopGroup())
            .protocol(HttpProtocol.HTTP11)
            .handle((request, response) -> {
                if (request.method().equals(HttpMethod.OPTIONS)) 
                    return response
                        .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                        .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE")
                        .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization")
                        .sendHeaders();
                else 
                    ???????
            })
            .route(this.provider::run)
            .bindUntilJavaShutdown(Duration.ofSeconds(30), this::onStart);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone suddenly needs

```
private @NotNull CorsConfig getCorsConfig() {
    return CorsConfigBuilder.forAnyOrigin()
            .allowNullOrigin()
            .allowCredentials()
            .allowedRequestMethods(HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST, HttpMethod.DELETE, HttpMethod.PUT, HttpMethod.PATCH)
            .allowedRequestHeaders("Content-Type", "Authorization")
            .build();
}

public void run() {
    HttpServer.create()
            .host(this.config.getHost())
            .port(this.config.getPort())
            .protocol(HttpProtocol.HTTP11)
            .doOnConnection(this::handler)
            .route(this.provider::run)
            .bindUntilJavaShutdown(Duration.ofSeconds(30), this::onStart);
}

private void addHandler() {
    this.connection.addHandlerLast(new CorsHandler(getCorsConfig()));
}
```